# radius of convergence of ${3^{k^2}}{x^{k^2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

find the interval of convergence

$\Sigma _{k=0} ^{\infty} 3^{k^{2}} x^{k^{2}}$

The radius of convergence of this series is 1/3 by the book.

but the answer and what i think is so different

what i think is that $R=\limsup |a_k|^{1/k}$ and i think $a_k=3^{k^2} or 3^{k^2}x^k$

how can i do?

i want to use $R=\limsup |a_k|^{1/k}$ or R=$\lim(|a_k|/|a_{k+1}|)$

Comment: "The book" is right, actually $a_n=3^n$ if $n$ is a square and $a_n=0$ if $n$ is not a square.

Answer (score 0):

The book is right. When you apply your test, you want to compute the $\lim\sup$ of
$$
\lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}
$$
but you are doing it with the "wrong $n$." Since all coefficients $a_n$ are zero unless $n$ is of the form $k^2$, you should compute the $\lim\sup$ of
$$
\lvert 3^{k^2}\rvert^{1/k^2},
$$
**not** of 
$$
\lvert 3^{k^2}\rvert^{1/k}.
$$

*(For the ratio of the radius, you will have some trouble there due to the fact that most of the coefficients are zero.)*